# XCode linker error after migrating to Cocoa Pods

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, cocoapods

## The problem

I'm pretty new when it comes to iOS development and XCode, so please comment and let me know if any details are missing from the question.

We have migrated an SDK from downloadable archive files to Cocoa Pods. One of our partners tried using our Pod, but the XCode linker gave the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGContainerOpener", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The Pod file in the project is:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'

target 'Demo' do

pod 'GoogleAppIndexing'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'OurPod', :git => 'https://github.com/AcmeCorp/OurPod.git'

end

target 'DemoTests' do

end
```

## Other settings

- We are opening the `xcworkspace` file (*not* the `xcode.proj` file).

## What have I tried

- I have tried to search the error but found nothing relevant.

Any idea what should I be looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did u open the xcworkspace ? you should be opening the xcworkspace instead of xcode.proj file.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yes, updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Met with the same problem while trying to add **Google Tag Manager** and **GoogleAnalytics** to my app

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGContainerOpener", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I think you have missed some library.
Try adding **libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a** to your project.
This had fixed my compilation error